# How to change my device name?

Tags: hostname

I want to change my device name but I have not found any option in the settings to do it. I am using Ubuntu for first time. Is there any way to change the device name that appears when I lock the desktop?

Answer (score 19):

Here is the command line way:

Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and enter `sudo hostname newname`. Replace `newname` of your device by the new name that you want to call your device. Enter your password.

Then, edit the oldname in `/etc/hostname`

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

and change the old name. Do the same in `/etc/hosts`

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Now you're done.

Comment: Jos: One point, The user might need to edit the `/etc/hosts` file too and replace the old hostname with the new one.

Comment: I made a small edit ;)

Comment: Never seen that GUI @Rinzwind. I wonder what other utilities are out there that are not installed by default, but would otherwise be useful.

Comment: Oh would not surprise me if there are more than 1000. I have seen so many nifty small gui tools that the gnome devs in the old days considered unwanted due to preferring the command line method :P

Comment: @Rinzwind @Randeep or you can change host name using `gksudo gedit /etc/hostname`

Answer (score 2):

You can change the host name from terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
gksu gedit /etc/hostname
```

this will open hostname(/etc) file in `gedit`,you can change your host name there and save the file.just restart your system and your host name is changed and when you lock the system that name will appears in top left corner of the desktop.However you can change the name of the user in **System Settings**->**User Accounts** click on the user in the right pane and change the name.logout and login again to see the change.